# Firebase How to get parent node from a query

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this simple query:

```
var userz = firebase.database().ref()
.child("accounts")
.orderByChild("userId")
.equalTo(fbid)
.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    ...
});
```

With this structure:
**- accounts

---- IdAccount

-------- Name

-------- userId

-------- provider**

When I ask **snapshot.key**, I get back "accounts" value.

I just want to know which "IdAccount" value I got when I did this query and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I changed "value" to "child_added" and it worked !**

```
 var userz = firebase.database().ref()
    .child("accounts")
    .orderByChild("userId")
    .equalTo(fbid)
    .once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        ...
    });
```